# Linq join, group, count where count greater than value

Tags: c#, linq, count, conditional-statements, linq-group

I have the following linq expression that lets me join two tables, group them by a `DSCID`, and then get a count of the grouped values:

```
var qryGeoApppendCount =
              from a in append
              join g in geo
              on a.Field<string>("RNO")
              equals g.Field<string>("RNO")
              group g by g.Field<int>("DSCID") into appendGeo
              select new
              {
                DscId = appendGeo.Key,
                DscIdCount = appendGeo.Count()
              };
```

I need to take this just one step further by only selecting the counts greater than 1.  I tried something like this:

```
select new
{
    DscId = appendGeo.Key,
    DscIdCount = appendGeo.Count(n => n.Count > 1)
};
```

but this didn't work. I need to be able to throw an error whenever `qryGeoAppendQuery` returns records with counts > 1, so ideally the query would be wrapped in an if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var qryGeoApppendCount =
              (from a in append
              join g in geo
              on a.Field<string>("RNO")
              equals g.Field<string>("RNO")
              group g by g.Field<int>("DSCID") into appendGeo
              select new
              {
                DscId = appendGeo.Key,
                DscIdCount = appendGeo.Count()
              })
              .Where(a => a.DscIdCount > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do...

```
select new
{
  DscId = appendGeo.Key,
  DscIdCount = appendGeo.Where(n => n.Count > 1).Count()
};
```

or if you just want to know if there exist any...

```
select new
{
  DscId = appendGeo.Key,
  ThrowException = appendGeo.Any(n => n.Count > 1)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var qryGeoApppendCount =
          from a in append
          join g in geo
          on a.Field<string>("RNO")
          equals g.Field<string>("RNO")
          group g by g.Field<int>("DSCID") into appendGeo
          where appendGeo.Count() > 1
          select new
          {
            DscId = appendGeo.Key,
            DscIdCount = appendGeo.Count()
          };
```

Can't you add a where clause before the select? It worked in my example but I'm not sure without seeing the data.

Comment: I was hoping to count where duplicate DSCID values occur in the joined table, not simply whether the joined table had a record count greater than 1.  Thanks a lot though for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT  [SubsNumber], sum([Usage_MB])/1024 as GB FROM [VASCDR].[dbo].[nrmSubsDailyMBUsage] where SubsNumber ='" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "'" group by [SubsNumber] ;
```

Is how to do it using c#